# Voltage drop label spacing better way

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

So this is my code right now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to[cI, l=2$i_o$] ++(0,5) to [short] ++(2.5, 0) coordinate(nearCtrlCur) to [R = 100 <\ohm>,v=$v_1$]++(0,-5) to[short]++(-2.5,0);
            \draw(nearCtrlCur) to [R = 25 <\ohm>]++(2.5,0) coordinate(near25Ohm) to [R = 200 <\ohm>,v=$v_2$]++(0, -5) coordinate(below200Ohm) to[short]++(-2.5, 0);
            \draw(near25Ohm) to [R = 50 <\ohm>,  i>^= $i_o$]++(2.5,0) coordinate(near50Ohm) to [R = 5 <\ohm>]++(0, -2.5);
            \draw($(near50Ohm) + (-0.5, 0)$) to[open, v = $v_3$] ++(0, -5);
            \draw(below200Ohm) to[short] ++(2.5,0) coordinate (belowCtrlV) to [cV_=$5 i_o$] ++(0, 2.5);
            \draw(near50Ohm) to[R = 20 <\ohm>]++(2.5, 0); 
            \draw(belowCtrlV) to[short] ++(2.5, 0)to [V,v_=38.5 <\volt>] ++(0, 5);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I am trying to mimic this:

[image]

Is there a way to get the voltage labels `v_1`, `v_2`, and `v_3` such that

1. The spacings between the vertical line and `v_1` and `v_2` is the same as that between the vertical line and `v_3`.
2. The positive and negative signs for `v_1` and `v_2` are positioned in such a way that it is similar to that in `v_3`. That is, the plus sign has equal relative position from the respective top right corner, and the minus sign as well from the respective bottom right corner.

I was wondering if there is a "general" way of doing so for all the voltages, because mine is somehow ad-hoc for doing `v_3`, and the voltage labels for `v_1` and `v_2` can only be applied to only one passive component.

Comment: Putting a voltage on to[open] was clever, but the rules for automatic placement are obviously different for different components (usually a function of component size).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution replaces the automatic placement of + and - with manual placement with nodes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}% to avoid cropping
%\usepackage{pgfplots}% not used here
%\usepackage{float}% friends don't left friends use [H]
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
%\usepackage{caption}% not used here
\begin{document}
    \ctikzset{voltage/american plus={}}% disable +
    \ctikzset{voltage/american minus={}}% disable -
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to[cI, l=2$i_o$] ++(0,5) to [short,-*] ++(2.5, 0) coordinate(nearCtrlCur) to [R= 100 <\ohm>,v=$v_1$,-*]++(0,-5)
              coordinate (B1) to[short]++(-2.5,0);
            \draw(nearCtrlCur) to [R = 25 <\ohm>, -*]++(2.5,0) coordinate(near25Ohm) to [R = 200 <\ohm>,v=$v_2$,-*]++(0, -5) 
              coordinate(below200Ohm) to[short]++(-2.5, 0);
            \draw(near25Ohm) to [R = 50 <\ohm>,  i>^= $i_o$,-*]++(2.5,0) coordinate(near50Ohm) to [R = 5 <\ohm>]++(0, -2.5)
              node[left]{$v_3$};
            \draw(below200Ohm) to[short,-*] ++(2.5,0) coordinate (belowCtrlV) to [cV_=$5 i_o$] ++(0, 2.5);
            \draw(near50Ohm) to[R = 20 <\ohm>]++(2.5, 0); 
            \draw(belowCtrlV) to[short] ++(2.5, 0)to [V,v_=38.5 <\volt>] ++(0, 5);
            \path (nearCtrlCur) node[below left]{$+$}
                  (B1) node[above left] {$-$}
                  (near25Ohm) node[below left]{$+$}
                  (below200Ohm) node[above left] {$-$}
                  (near50Ohm) node[below left]{$+$}
                  (belowCtrlV)  node[above left] {$-$};
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

John's answer is right on spot. My solution would be slightly different, though. (Please notice: I have an experimental version of the voltage-drawing routines, that will be available shortly, so your results may differ a bit).

Voltage positions in `circuitikz` are designed to work just on one component, and their placement depend on the component shape (more in the next version, to avoid overlap with asymmetric elements).

So what I propose in this case is to use a macro to "slap" a voltage in a fixed position with respect a node, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%
% path to move away x (#1) and y (#2) a voltage indication (#3)
% (it will leave the path position unchanged)
%
\newcommand{\slapvxy}[3]{%
    ++({-1*(#1)},#2) to[open, v={#3}] ++(0,{-2*(#2)}) ++(#1,#2)
}
%
% specific one we'll use here
%
\newcommand{\slapv}[1]{\slapvxy{0.7}{2.5}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            % name the element
            \draw (0,0) to[cI, l=2$i_o$] ++(0,5) to [short] ++(2.5, 0) coordinate(nearCtrlCur) to [R = 100 <\ohm>,name=R1]++(0,-5) to[short]++(-2.5,0);
            % position the voltage (usage outside the path)
            \path (R1.center) \slapv{$v_1$};
            \draw(nearCtrlCur) to [R = 25 <\ohm>]++(2.5,0) coordinate(near25Ohm) to [R = 200 <\ohm>,name=R2]++(0, -5) coordinate(below200Ohm) to[short]++(-2.5, 0);
            \path (R2.center) \slapv{$v_2$};
            \draw(near25Ohm) to [R = 50 <\ohm>,  i>^= $i_o$]++(2.5,0) coordinate(near50Ohm) to [R = 5 <\ohm>]++(0, -2.5)
            % position the voltage (usage inside the path)
            \slapv{$v_3$};
            % \draw($(near50Ohm) + (-0.5, 0)$) to[open, v = $v_3$] ++(0, -5);
            \draw(below200Ohm) to[short] ++(2.5,0) coordinate (belowCtrlV) to [cV_=$5 i_o$] ++(0, 2.5);
            \draw(near50Ohm) to[R = 20 <\ohm>]++(2.5, 0);
            \draw(belowCtrlV) to[short] ++(2.5, 0)to [V,v_=38.5 <\volt>] ++(0, 5);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]