# Voltage label too close

Tags: circuitikz

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw(0,0) to[V = $\vec{V}_g$] ++(0, 3) to[R = 50 <\ohm>] ++(3, 0) to[C = 1<\micro\farad>, v = $\vec{V}_o$] ++(0, -3) to[short] ++(-3, 0);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As we can see, `$\vec{V}_o$` is almost touching the capacitor. How to adjust the spacing for the voltage label?

Actually, can [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550017/voltage-drop-label-spacing-better-way) potentially solve the problem? Note that what I am trying to draw is based off of this:

[image]

Comment: A dirty trick: `to[C = 1<\micro\farad>, v = $\vec{V}_o$ ~] ++(0, -3)` (observe ` ~` after `$\vec{V}_o$`), however, better is replace `v=$\vec{V}_o$` with `a=$\vec{V}_o$`

Comment: Didn't `voltage shift` (manual around page 142, section "voltage position" help?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here... one is to wait a couple of days until v1.2.0 is out, with the new voltage position routine. So you will have your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw(0,0) to[V = $\vec{V}_g$] ++(0, 3) to[R = 50 <\ohm>] ++(3, 0) 
    to[C = 1<\micro\farad>, v = $\vec{V}_o$] ++(0, -3) to[short] ++(-3, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

producing this, without any tweak:

[image]

Otherwise, you can use `voltage shift` (see around page 142 in the manual, section *Voltage position*), which will move both signs and label, or `voltage/american label distance` which will move just the label (*notice that the magic number will have a slightly different meaning in the new version*)

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz-1.1.2}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw(0,0) to[V = $\vec{V}_g$] ++(0, 3) to[R = 50 <\ohm>] ++(3, 0)
    to[C = 1<\micro\farad>, v = $\vec{V}_o$, voltage/american label distance=1.4]
    ++(0, -3) to[short] ++(-3, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550194/voltage-label-not-moving-in-vertical-direction/550223#550223 and show us, how you will solve this OP's problems. I delete my answer(s) .

Comment: @Zarko no need to delete your answer, it showed interesting options!

Comment: Thank you for nice words, however your answer is on the "right track" (far better/correct). Also OP so far didn't see any value in them. So, lets stay both deleted.

Comment: ANd of course, +1 for your answer ...