# Voltage label not moving in vertical direction

Tags: circuitikz

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550164/voltage-label-too-close).

This time, I would like to move the voltage label downward.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw(0,0) to [I, l^= $5\phase{\ang{0}}$] ++(0, 3) coordinate(nearCurSrc) to[C = $-j8$] ++(3, 0) to[L = $j4$] ++(0, -3) coordinate(belowInd) to[short]++(-3, 0);
            \draw(belowInd) to[short] ++(3, 0) to[V, v_= $20\phase{\ang{90}}$] ++(0, 3) coordinate(nearVSrc) to[R, l_= 12<\ohm>] ++(-3, 0);
            \draw(nearCurSrc) to [short]++(0, 1.5) coordinate(curSrcUp) to [C = $-j4$, v = $\vspace{1cm}\vec{V}_g$] (curSrcUp -| nearVSrc) to[short] (nearVSrc);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I also tried `\raisebox`, but that didn't work either. How to fix it?

Comment: The `\phase` used in your example is undefined.

Comment: Like the answer to your previous question, replacing `v = $\vspace{1cm}\vec{V}_g$` by `a = $\vec{V}_g$` should solve your problem.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ oops, you need the `steinmetz` package. Sorry, I removed it by accident

Comment: Note that \vspace only works in something like a \parbox. Since tikz centers text in nodes (labels), moving the baseline doesn't work either.  The easiest solution would be to throw in a strut like \rule{0pt}{...}.

Comment: This is basically the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550164/voltage-label-too-close --- just add `voltage/american label distance=1.4` or wait  until v1.2.0...

Comment: Hi @Rmano, yes it does.